# Is it possible to share a folder without Admin rights, just like on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to share a folder without Admin rights, just like on Windows XP?

Comment: More information is required.  What profil3e owns the folder that you want to share?  Of course just turning on the ability to share files requires an administrator to enable it.